# The shell says 'Invalid Syntax'

Tags: python, syntax

```
    #This will loop the try statement until an integer is entered as the guess1 variable
    while True:
        #The try statement will see if the guess variable is given an integer value,
        #if not then it will print "You did not enter an integer. This is not a
        #valid answer
        try:
            #This will allow the user to enter their answer and
            #store it in the guess1 variable
            guess1 = int(input(""))
            #This will break the while loop if an integer is entered as the guess1 variable
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("You did not enter an integer. This is not a valid answer. Please enter a valid integer")
            print("Answer the quesiton appropiately" + "What is " + (str(first2) + op + str(second2) + "?")
    if guess1 == answer1:
        #If the guess1 variable is equal to the answer1 variable, then
        #"Correct!" will be printed and one point would be
        #added to the score
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        #Else "Incorrect" would be printed
        print ("Incorrect")
```

The shell states that there is an invalid syntax with the colon when I typed 'guess1 == answer1:'.

Comment: Count the parentheses on the previous line.

Comment: And that's why you use `format` and don't concatenate strings with `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't close a tag on the second line in your except statement. Add an extra ")" to the end.

```
print("Answer the quesiton appropiately" + "What is " + (str(first2) + op + str(second2) + "?"))
```